Did the Space Shuttle weigh itself before deorbit?
Back in the day, it was standard for commercial airlines to calculate the mass of an airliner before takeoff, using assumptions of average passenger  weight along with accounts of fuel loaded or burned in previous flights..
After a crash in 2003 (which was largely due to erroneous assumptions of passenger weight) Onboard Weight and Balance Systems (OWBS) were developed. These systems use compression of the landing gear suspension to measure the actual weight of the loaded aircraft before take-off.
The idea was to switch from calculating mass to actually measuring mass in order to avoid errors (and accidents).
Presumably re-entry mass of the Shuttle was an important parameter. The mass of the space shuttle would be lower at the time of deorbit than at take-off. Was the deorbit mass of the space shuttle measured or calculated?
Obviously landing gear compression could not be used in orbit. But was there an alternate method of measuring mass? F=ma, so a thruster firing accompanied by accurate measurement of thrust and acceleration would do the job. Inertial navigation system accelerometers have 0.001-0.01milli-g accuracy and load cells  are available with 0.02% accuracy.

You can easily measure mass by trying to accelerate it. That's what the sensors in the landing gears are measuring anyway with the acceleration provided for free by Earth's gravity. When you can't use gravity use rockets.

@slebetman You can't measure your mass accelerating yourself in Earth's gravity. You always need some external force.

@asdfex Not in a free-fall. But you can on the ground. Earth's gravity will continue accelerating you even if you are sitting still on the ground.

Where do you draw the line between "measurement" and "calculation"? Is using the fuel gauge to determine the remaining propellant volume, and converting that to mass measuring or calculating? I would think almost any method of measuring mass other than a balance scale will require calculation. Even a common bathroom scale in reality "measures" an electrical current and "calculates" your weight from that.

"So aircraft switched from calculating mass to actually measuring mass in order to avoid errors" No, one or two airliner self-weighing systems were offered but rarely used. They were apparently maintenance nightmares. The first gen systems (A300 basically) were for verification only, you still needed to do the calculations. The second gen systems (777F) could be used operationally.

@user71659 ... thanks for the info. OP edited appropriately.

@NuclearHoagie ... good point. Calculations can be 100% accurate. It is the inputted assumptions and measurements which have errors. In the accident calculation, the assumed average passenger weight was 185lb. Actual weights taken from medical records showed the average weight was well over 200lb (working from memory here). The error was in the assumption, not the calculation.

Just out of curiosity, what crash are you referring to that spurred the development of OBWBS? The only crash I know of that was related to weight and balance was Air Midwest 5481 in 2003. (Which did push the FAA to redo their official W&B calculation methods, but I don't think Beechcraft have any onboard W&B systems even today.)

@DarthPseudonym ... You are right. It was Air Midwest Flight 5481 ( I blame Chat GPT for telling me it was in an American Eagle flight in1994) . Misestimate of weight was one causal component, but another was faulty maintenance which caused reduced range of motion of the elevator control surface.

Not only re-entry mass, but center of gravity (CG) locations, touchdown weight, etc.
Mass properties were calculated on the ground and uplinked. The responsible flight control position was FDO "Fido" the Flight Dynamics Officer.
They had ground software to assist in the task. The FDO Console Handbook Volume IV Chapter 4.3 Maneuver Generation spends pages and pages on the process. Here's a short quote

The purpose of the mass properties task for deorbit prep and entry phase
operations is to compute predicted orbiter mass properties at the following points;
before and after the deorbit burn, EI, TAEM, and landing. These include weight,
CG’s, and engine trims. The predicted weights and CG’s at EI and Mach 3.5
(M3) are also of interest to the Guidance, Navigation, and Control (GNC) Flight
Controller for glideslope, elevon schedule, and body bending filter selection
requirements during entry.

Here's a high level view of the calculation process from Volume III of the console handbook:

Procedures entail configuring
PMP displays to represent groups of payload masses, together with Orbiter
consumables, using either telemetry data (for current values) or predicted data. These
groups can be summarized as cargo, cryogenics, and non-propulsive consumables. Once
mass property information for individual groups is determined, each is added together and
combined with data for the inert Orbiter and propulsive consumables to determine the
entire Orbiter mass properties.

Much of the inputs came from other flight controller positions as stated back in Volume IV:

...the flight controller
positions of Environmental and Consumables Management (EECOM), Electrical
Generation and Integrated Loading (EGIL), and MMACS. These positions are
responsible for providing much of the predicted consumables information
required for EOM mass properties predictions.

Here's a quote from further along in Volume IV just to confirm that they got uplinked:

If the expected post deorbit burn weight is very close to the weight switchpoint
(within 200 lb), it may be desirable to bias the weight that is uplinked with the
PEG 4 targets, which would allow some margin between the burnout weight and
the switchpoint weight.

Since it would be nice to have a linkable reference, I'll point to my friend and former FDO Roger Balettie's website. He mentions this process in passing where he talks about his last shift as a FDO:

TOTAL WT: 224971
This was noting that we had done a routine update of the current Orbiter weight (in pounds), based on various things – including fuel expended so far, cargo/payloads transferred, consumables used, etc.
It was important to know the vehicle weight for not only on-orbit state vector propagation, but also in the event of an unplanned or emergency deorbit situation to know if we needed to burn off extra fuel to get down below a certain maximum down-weight level.

The weight was visible to the crew on the Deorbit Maneuver computer display and could be changed by them there.

It was also read up to the crew during Deorbit Preparation to be entered on the Burn Pads.

References:

FDO Console Handbook Volume III Orbit and Volume IV Deorbit/Entry
GNC Insertion/Orbit/Deorbit Workbook
Deorbit Prep Checklist
Entry Checklist

Acronymology:

EI - Entry Interface, 400,000 feet altitude
EOM - End of Mission
MMACS - Mechanical, Maintenance, Arm and Crew Systems flight control position
PEG - Powered Explicit Guidance
PMP - Paperless Mass Properties calculation software
TAEM - Terminal Area Energy Management, ~ 85,000 feet altitude


If I’m reading this correctly, it sounds like they only calculated the weight, rather than directly measuring it. Is that accurate, or did they do something w/ a known thrust level & orbital parameter change/etc to calculate the mass?

@fyrepenguin I edited the answer to add some info. Briefly, they took the prelaunch mass properties for the inert orbiter and got consumables masses from the other flight control teams, then calculated the current mass properties using their "Paperless Mass Properties" software. I did not see anything about propulsive maneuvers to validate the results.

@fyrepenguin the document does mention that errors in the mass calculation can cause burn times to differ from what is predicted. "If TGO counts down at a different
rate, one of several anomalies may exist. The Orbiter weight used by guidance may be
in error, causing measured acceleration levels to differ from those expected by
guidance." (TGO is time to go in the burn) So it looks like they were cognizant of that potential source of error during burns but didn't do special validation burns.

@OrganicMarble so is it fair to answer, "No, the space shuttle did not weigh itself. Mass was calculated instead of measured. But during the deorbit burn, acceleration was used to double check the calculated mass and the burn adjusted accordingly in real time" ?

@Woody The burn kind of "adjusted" itself, it would burn until it reached the burn targets or ran out of prop; no realtime mass error correction. But otherwise yeah.

@OrganicMarble. Perhaps you could add a note on how the predicted mass properties and real-time mass properties were used by the ground system and flight hardware, respectively.  On Minuteman, there was a precomputed target telemetry done by ground equipment.  Flight hardware compared measured velocities to those in the telemetry file and treated the difference  as an error. The error file drove the flight control algorithm that corrected the error in a way that minimized velocity and position errors at a future point in time. But then we had about 1k of storage to work with.

@PhilSweet fascinating anecdote! The question is about how the mass value was obtained though, not how it was used, and I try to stay on subject.

@OrganicMarble Sure, but why would you even need it?  And at what point in the flight would you need it?

@PhilSweet Great questions! Feel free to ask them.

It's not like the weight is going to change that unpredictably. They know the weight of the shuttle itself before takeoff. They know the weight of whatever large equipment (satellites, parts of the ISS, etc.) is being loaded or unloaded during the mission. They know how much fuel is in the tanks and how much that weighs. After that the only possibly unpredictable part is how much the crew's weight changes based on their diet during the mission, and that is likely negligible compared to everything else.
